Stuck on making my login GUI work in Java
I am fairly new to programming and I've started developing or making GUI to test my ability. I tried doing a log in and sign up with only using hash map and arrays only to store the values. Everytime I click the sign up or log in register it doesnt prompt me to the class, is there anything that I've done wrong? This will be a lot of help to me.
Thank you so so much
import java.util.*;
 
 
 
 
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        IDandPasswords idandPasswords = new IDandPasswords();
        LoginPage LoginPage = new LoginPage(idandPasswords.getLoginInfo(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class LoginPage implements ActionListener {
 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
    JTextField userIDField = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField userPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
    JLabel userIDLabel = new JLabel("userID:");
    JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("password:");
    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel();
    JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel registrationPanel = new JPanel();
    HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ArrayList<String> registrationInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
 
    LoginPage(HashMap<String,String> loginInfoOriginal, ArrayList<String> registrationInfoOriginal){
 
        logininfo = loginInfoOriginal;
        registrationInfo = registrationInfoOriginal;
 
        userIDLabel.setBounds(50,100,75,25);
        userPasswordLabel.setBounds(50,150,75,25);
 
        messageLabel.setBounds(125,250,250,35);
        messageLabel.setFont(new Font(null,Font.ITALIC,25));
 
        userIDField.setBounds(125,100,200,25);
        userPasswordField.setBounds(125,150,200,25);
 
        loginButton.setBounds(125,200,100,25);
        loginButton.setFocusable(false);
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);
 
        resetButton.setBounds(225,200,100,25);
        resetButton.setFocusable(false);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
 
        registerButton.setBounds(125,300,200,25);
        registerButton.setFocusable(false);
        registerButton.addActionListener(this);
 
        loginPanel.add(userIDLabel);
        loginPanel.add(userPasswordLabel);
        loginPanel.add(messageLabel);
        loginPanel.add(userIDField);
        loginPanel.add(userPasswordField);
        loginPanel.add(loginButton);
        loginPanel.add(resetButton);
 
        registrationPanel.setLayout(null);
        registrationPanel.add(registerButton);
 
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem loginMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Login");
        JMenuItem registerMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Register");
 
        loginMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.remove(registrationPanel);
                frame.add(loginPanel);
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
 
        registerMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.remove(loginPanel);
                frame.add(registrationPanel);
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
 
        menu.add(loginMenuItem);
        menu.add(registerMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(loginPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 
        if (e.getSource() == resetButton) {
            userIDField.setText("");
            userPasswordField.setText("");
        }
 
        if (e.getSource() == loginButton) {
 
            String userID = userIDField.getText();
            String password = String.valueOf(userPasswordField.getPassword());
 
            if (logininfo.containsKey(userID)) {
                if (logininfo.get(userID).equals(password)) {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                    messageLabel.setText("Login successful");
                    frame.dispose();
                    WelcomePage welcomePage = new WelcomePage(userID);
                } else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    messageLabel.setText("Wrong password");
                }
 
            } else {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                messageLabel.setText("username not found");
            }
        }
 
        if (e.getSource() == registerButton) {
            String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Username:");
            String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Password:");
            logininfo.put(username, password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration successful!");
        }
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
 
 
 
class WelcomePage {
 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
    JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Hello!");
 
    WelcomePage(String userID){
 
        welcomeLabel.setBounds(0,0,200,35);
        welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font(null,Font.PLAIN,25));
        welcomeLabel.setText("Hello "+userID);
 
        logoutButton.setBounds(300, 10, 100, 25);
        logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
                LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(new HashMap<>(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
        });
 
        frame.add(welcomeLabel);
        frame.add(logoutButton);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420, 420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.HashMap;
 
public class IDandPasswords {
 
    private HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
 
    public IDandPasswords(){
        logininfo.put("Bro","pizza");
        logininfo.put("Brometheus","PASSWORD");
        logininfo.put("BroCode","abc123");
    }
 
    public HashMap<String,String> getLoginInfo(){
        return logininfo;
    }
}

I tried prompting the button into the sign up, and log in page / class but it doesnt take me to the page.

Your LoginPage is also an action listener (bit weird), but no code you pasted adds any instance of LoginPage as actionlistener to a thing, therefore, that extensive actionPerformed method in your LoginPage class would never even be called. Your logout button makes a second instance of LoginPage and forgets about it immediately (local variables disappear once a method ends).

@rzwitserloot Their LoginPage constructor creates a JFrame and sets it visible.

A CardLayout is something worth looking at

class but it doesnt take me to the page. - Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use CardLayout. It has a working demo that demonstrates how to swap panels.

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Because of the following line (in constructor of class LoginPage), you need to also set bounds for loginPanel and registrationPanel.
frame.setLayout(null);

You also forgot to set layout manager for loginPanel to null. Here is your code with corrections.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class LoginPage implements ActionListener {
 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
    JTextField userIDField = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField userPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
    JLabel userIDLabel = new JLabel("userID:");
    JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("password:");
    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel();
    JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel registrationPanel = new JPanel();
    HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ArrayList<String> registrationInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
 
    LoginPage(HashMap<String,String> loginInfoOriginal, ArrayList<String> registrationInfoOriginal){
 
        logininfo = loginInfoOriginal;
        registrationInfo = registrationInfoOriginal;
 
        userIDLabel.setBounds(50,100,75,25);
        userPasswordLabel.setBounds(50,150,75,25);
 
        messageLabel.setBounds(125,250,250,35);
        messageLabel.setFont(new Font(null,Font.ITALIC,25));
 
        userIDField.setBounds(125,100,200,25);
        userPasswordField.setBounds(125,150,200,25);
 
        loginButton.setBounds(125,200,100,25);
        loginButton.setFocusable(false);
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);
 
        resetButton.setBounds(225,200,100,25);
        resetButton.setFocusable(false);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
 
        registerButton.setBounds(125,300,200,25);
        registerButton.setFocusable(false);
        registerButton.addActionListener(this);
 
        loginPanel.add(userIDLabel);
        loginPanel.add(userPasswordLabel);
        loginPanel.add(messageLabel);
        loginPanel.add(userIDField);
        loginPanel.add(userPasswordField);
        loginPanel.add(loginButton);
        loginPanel.add(resetButton);
        loginPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        loginPanel.setLayout(null);
 
        registrationPanel.setLayout(null);
        registrationPanel.add(registerButton);
        registrationPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
 
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem loginMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Login");
        JMenuItem registerMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Register");
 
        loginMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("loginMenuItem");
                frame.remove(registrationPanel);
                frame.add(loginPanel);
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
 
        registerMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("registerMenuItem");
                frame.remove(loginPanel);
                frame.add(registrationPanel);
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
 
        menu.add(loginMenuItem);
        menu.add(registerMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(loginPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("actionPerformed");
        if (e.getSource() == resetButton) {
            userIDField.setText("");
            userPasswordField.setText("");
        }
 
        if (e.getSource() == loginButton) {
 
            String userID = userIDField.getText();
            String password = String.valueOf(userPasswordField.getPassword());
 
            if (logininfo.containsKey(userID)) {
                if (logininfo.get(userID).equals(password)) {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                    messageLabel.setText("Login successful");
                    frame.dispose();
                    WelcomePage welcomePage = new WelcomePage(userID);
                } else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    messageLabel.setText("Wrong password");
                }
 
            } else {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                messageLabel.setText("username not found");
            }
        }
 
        if (e.getSource() == registerButton) {
            String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Username:");
            String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Password:");
            logininfo.put(username, password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration successful!");
        }
    }
}

Here is how it looks when launched.

And after clicking on Register [menu] item.


Is there an edit that could be made to the title of the question which would help other people find it, if it's a useful question?

Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

This is how it should be done. Note that below code is [currently] a work in progress. Rather than write lots of explanations regarding the below code, you should first read through the entire tutorial entitled Creating a GUI With Swing and also read about lambda expressions (including method references). Then come back and look at the below code.
EDIT
Rather than using JOptionPane for registering new users, the below code displays a JDialog for that purpose.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginPag implements Runnable {
    private static final String  EMPTY = "          ";
    private static final String  LOGIN = "Login";
    private static final String  REGISTRATION = "Registration";

    private CardLayout  cardLayout;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JLabel  messageLabel;
    private JPanel  cardPanel;
    private JPasswordField  userPasswordField;
    private JTextField  userIdField;
    private Map<String, String>  loginInfo;

    public LoginPag(Map<String, String> loginInfo) {
        this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
    }

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createCardPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem loginMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Login");
        loginMenuItem.addActionListener(this::showLogin);
        JMenuItem registerMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Register");
        registerMenuItem.addActionListener(this::showRegistration);
        menu.add(loginMenuItem);
        menu.add(registerMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createCardPanel() {
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        cardPanel.add(createLoginPanel(), LOGIN);
        cardPanel.add(createRegistrationPanel(), REGISTRATION);
        return cardPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createLoginButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel loginButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton loginButton = new JButton(LOGIN);
        loginButton.addActionListener(this::doLogin);
        loginButtonsPanel.add(loginButton);
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(this::reset);
        loginButtonsPanel.add(resetButton);
        return loginButtonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createLoginFormPanel() {
        JPanel loginFormPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 10));
        loginFormPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        JLabel userIdLabel = new JLabel("User ID");
        loginFormPanel.add(userIdLabel);
        userIdField = new JTextField(10);
        loginFormPanel.add(userIdField);
        JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        loginFormPanel.add(userPasswordLabel);
        userPasswordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        loginFormPanel.add(userPasswordField);
        return loginFormPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createLoginPanel() {
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        messageLabel = new JLabel(EMPTY, JLabel.CENTER);
        loginPanel.add(messageLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        loginPanel.add(createLoginFormPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        loginPanel.add(createLoginButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        return loginPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createRegistrationPanel() {
        JPanel registrationPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton registrationButton = new JButton(REGISTRATION);
        registrationButton.addActionListener(this::register);
        registrationPanel.add(registrationButton);
        return registrationPanel;
    }

    private void doLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        String userID = userIdField.getText();
        String password = new String(userPasswordField.getPassword());
        if (loginInfo.containsKey(userID)) {
            if (loginInfo.get(userID).equals(password)) {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                messageLabel.setText("Login successful");
//                WelcomePage welcomePage = new WelcomePage(userID);
            }
            else {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                messageLabel.setText("Wrong password");
            }
        }
        else {
            messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
            messageLabel.setText("username not found");
        }        
    }

    private void register(ActionEvent event) {
        RegisterDialog rd = new RegisterDialog(frame, loginInfo);
        loginInfo = rd.getRegistration();
    }

    private void reset(ActionEvent event) {
        userIdField.setText("");
        userPasswordField.setText("");
        messageLabel.setText(EMPTY);
    }

    private void showLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, LOGIN);
    }

    private void showRegistration(ActionEvent event) {
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, REGISTRATION);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IDandPasswords idap = new IDandPasswords();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new LoginPag(idap.getLoginInfo()));
    }
}

class RegisterDialog extends JDialog {
    private JPasswordField  userPasswordField;
    private JTextField  userIdTextField;
    private Map<String, String>  map;

    public RegisterDialog(JFrame owner, Map<String, String> map) {
        super(owner, "Registration", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.map = map;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        add(createRegisterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getRegistration() {
        return map;
    }

    private void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
        dispose();
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
        registerButton.addActionListener(this::register);
        buttonsPanel.add(registerButton);
        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(this::cancel);
        buttonsPanel.add(cancelButton);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createRegisterPanel() {
        JPanel registerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel userIdLabel = new JLabel("User ID");
        registerPanel.add(userIdLabel, gbc);
        userIdTextField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        registerPanel.add(userIdTextField, gbc);
        JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        registerPanel.add(userPasswordLabel, gbc);
        userPasswordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        registerPanel.add(userPasswordField, gbc);
        return registerPanel;
    }

    private void register(ActionEvent event) {
        String usr = userIdTextField.getText();
        String pwd = new String(userPasswordField.getPassword());
        map.put(usr, pwd);
        cancel(event);
    }
}

Note that I can think of several improvements to the above code, like using keyboard shortcuts, for example Alt+L to activate the Login button. Also make the Login button disabled until both a [user] ID and a [user] password have been entered. And in the [Registration] dialog check whether the entered details do not already exist in the Map and display an error – via a JOptionPane – if they do. You will find details on how to do all that in the tutorial that I linked to, above.
